# How can I correctly apply the scalar calibration of vector magnetometers?

Tags: matlab, calibration, magnetometer

I need to calibrate a magnetometer using the method of Merayo with matlab. 
I have found [this code](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23398-magnetometers-calibration/content/MgnCalibration.m):

But I do not understand how I apply this technique. I fact I have the magnetic Data distorted, I apply the Magnetic Calibration.

```
[U,c] = MgnCalibration(X)
```

So I get U the Shape ellipsoid parameter and c the ellipsoid center.
And the calibrated measurement is:
     w = U*(v-c)

The problem is that when I calculate the corrected Data I have another order of values.

```
Data=[1750 1460 -3940]
CalibratedData=[0.4042 0.3820 -0.6860]
```

What I did not very well understood?
How can I use my magnetic data after this calibration?

Answer (score 0):

The calibrated data for each axis [mx=0.4042 my=0.3820 mz=-0.6860]  should now be independent of the orientation in 3D space in which the fluxgate finds itself for that specific measurement at that point in space. The Total Field calculated with sqrt(mx.mx+my.my+mz.mz) will be the calibrated Earth's Total magnetic field at that point.

If scaled properly this total field value should be the same as that measured by a proton or cesium vapor magnetometer